# Query giving division by zero error in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentage, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to run the following query which results me `postgres error: division by zero`

```
select 
    request_count,
    response_count, 
    (response_count*100) / (request_count+response_count) AS proportion 
from total_dummy_table;
```

How can I avoid and resolve the `division by zero` error?

Tried to fix using the below query but getting the same result as above

```
SELECT 
    request_count,
    response_count,
    (response_count*100) / (request_count) AS proportion 
FROM 
    total_dummy_table
ORDER BY 
    (response_count*100) /(CASE request_count WHEN 0 Then NULL ELSE request_count END) DESC NULLS FIRST
```

Please let me know where am I doing wrong, or how can I fix this.
Thanks!

**Result expectation:**

The query should return me something like below:

```
Request_count | Response_count | Proportion

1603423       |  585706        | 36.52
```

**Quick note:** Table total_dummy_table does not have column name `proportion` that is the addition to the result which have calculated proportion in it.

Comment: What do you want to display if `request_count+response_count` is zero ?

Comment: If request_count and response count is 0 I want the proportion column should display 0.

Comment: Do that at a higher level, see my answer for a potential solution...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
select request_count,response_count, 
case 
    when 
    request_count+response_count = 0 then 0 
    else
(response_count*100) / (request_count+response_count) 
end AS proportion 
from total_dummy_table;
```

Comment: Thank you Hourari, quick question and very dumb too- here the total count according to me is request_count, out of which how many people responded is a response_count. So my understanding says the total have to be just request_count not the addition of them? correct? I am just curious.

Comment: It depends of what do you want to calculate/display. My answer was to avoid the `divison by zero` error :)

Comment: NULLIF is a more appropriate solution to avoid divide by zero errors, and is also a much more simple solution.  I recommend the answer from diego

Comment: nullIf is better

Answer (score 52):

use NULLIF

```
something/NULLIF(column_name,0)
```

`NULLIF(col,val)` is shorthand for

```
CASE WHEN col=val THEN NULL ELSE col
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the right answer. Its tedious to repeat the denominator. Especially if its a big expression, you will the feel the pain repeating the whole denominator as in @Houari 's answer

Comment: I agree, this is the more succinct solution.  coding a case statement is unnecessary, and the real answer is Null not 0.